# Case with Oracle SGBD

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, case, where-clause

I am currently working with SpagoBI tool using the DBMS Oracle, I wanted to achieve a filter using a query that contains "Case" in the first place if no values are chosen at the filter, I will get a result of all columns, and when I chose a value from filter I will have another result proportional to this value.

I tried with this query:

```
select 
    price as price, qty as qty 
from 
    HR.TEST 
Where 
    year_column LIKE WHEN $P{year} = 'None' then year_column else $P{year} end
```

NB: I will filter through the year

- $P{Year}  is the value of the filter at the tool "SpagoBI" and its default value is None.
- I tried this query using the MySQL DBMS and it works but with oracle it did not work.

Comment: Please show the data types of the table columns and what does "does not work mean?"  We are not mind readers.

Comment: If `year_column` is a number than `LIKE` doesn't make sense. `LIKE` is for characters not for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Think of case as a **function** that returns a **SQL type**. In a predicate, you would always do

`where f(x) <operator> expression`

See this similar [question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:237794600346808562) in AskTom.